# Split 1 long txt column into 2 columns in pyspark:databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe column which has data as below.

```
event_list
PL:1547497782:1547497782~ST:1548593509:1547497782
PU:1547497782:1547497782~MU:1548611698:1547497782:1~MU:1548612195:1547497782:0~ST:1548627786:1547497782
PU:1547497782:1547497782~PU:1547497782:1547497782~ST:1548637508:1547497782
PL:1548631949:0
PL:1548619200:0~PU:1548623089:1548619435~PU:1548629541:1548625887~RE:1548629542:1548625887~PU:1548632702:1548629048~ST:1548635966:1548629048
PL:1548619583:1548619584~ST:1548619610:1548619609
PL:1548619850:0~ST:1548619850:0~PL:1548619850:0~ST:1548619850:0~PL:1548619850:1548619851~ST:1548619856:1548619855
```

I am only interested to have first 10 digits after `PL:` and first 10 digits after `ST:` (if exists). For PL split, I used

```
df.withColumn('PL', split(df['event_list'], '\:')[1])
```

for ST: since records have a different length that logic dose not work, i can use this

```
df.withColumn('ST', split(df['event_list'], '\ST:')[1])
```

which it returns `ST:1548619856:1548619855` and split the first part again. I have 1.5 M records so I was wondering if there is a better way.

here is expected output

```
PL              ST
154749778   1548593509
    null    1548627786
    null    1548637508
154863194   null
154861920   1548635966
154861958   1548619610
154861985   1548619856
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is using SparkSQL builtin function [str_to_map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map):

```
df.selectExpr("str_to_map(event_list, '~', ':') as map1") \
  .selectExpr(
    "split(map1['PL'],':')[0] as PL", 
    "split(map1['ST'],':')[0] as ST"
).show()
+----------+----------+
|        PL|        ST|
+----------+----------+
|1547497782|1548593509|
|      null|1548627786|
|      null|1548637508|
|1548631949|      null|
|1548619200|1548635966|
|1548619583|1548619610|
|1548619850|1548619850|
+----------+----------+
```

**Note:** you can replace the above *split* function to *substr* function (i.e. `substr(map1['PL'],1,10)`) in case you need exactly the first 10 chars.

Comment: Thanks @jxc, very fast and useful way! this select only PL and ST columns , what if I need to keep other columns as well?

Comment: @DanielG, what do you mean by `other columns`? can you elaborate and add the expected result? Basically, after str_to_map, it's a Map column and you just need to do some data manipulation on that Map.

Comment: yes, I meant if we have col1, col2 , event_list in data frame (i just provided event_list col in my question)  after str_to_map , we have only PL and ST a.k.a "Map columns" not col1 and co2

Comment: @DanielG,  just add them to the list, for example: `.selectExpr("col1", "col2", "split(map1['PL'],':')[0] as PL", "split(map1['ST'],':')[0] as ST")`

Answer (score 2):

try with a combination of [`substring_index`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) and substring

```
df.select(
 substring(
   substring_index(df['event_list'], 'PL:', -1), # Get the string starting from 'PL:'
  3, 10).as('PL')) # Skip the first 3 letters and take 10 chars
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `regexp_extract`, something like

```
val result = df.withColumn("PL", regexp_extract(col("event_list"),"PL\\:(.{0,10})\\:",1))
               .withColumn("ST", regexp_extract(col("event_list"),"ST\\:(.{0,10})\\:",1))
```